# OpenCV\Emgu Replicating Median filter in Paint.net

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I have this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCcQf.jpg

I am trying to make the areas near the bottom of the image fill in some of the black void area.

In Paint.NET i ran to the "Effects > Noise > Median" filter to see what I could do.
Using a percentile value of 100 and a radius value of 1 or 2 is replicating what I need
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRWmw.jpg

I looked through OpenCV\Emgu and noticed a "MedianBlur" method (CvInvoke.MedianBlur(dst, dst, 3);), hoping that it would accomplish what I needed it to do. It only takes 1 parameter and it produces weird results like these
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZQWs.jpg

Any ideas on how I can increase the size of each pixel like the Paint.NET filter?

Answer (score 0):

CvInvoke.Dilate(dst, dst, CvInvoke.GetStructuringElement(ElementShape.Ellipse, new Size(5, 5), new Point(-1, -1)), new Point(-1,-1), 1, BorderType.Reflect101, new MCvScalar(255,255,255) );